# json_encode, associative array needed in [ brackets ]

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using PHP, and in order to feed some data to an API using Curl, I need to format some strings and have been using json_encode. It works just fine for simpler bits, but this I can't figure out:

The API expects this:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "startTime": "2017-04-18T08:04:23.167Z",
  "endTime": "2017-04-18T08:04:23.167Z",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "displayName": "string"
    }
```

My code so far:

```
$data_set_pre = array(
    "id" => "",
    "startTime" => "2017-04-14T07:47:59.028Z",
    "endTime" => "2017-04-15T07:47:59.028Z",
    "contacts" => array("id" => "ahashofsomenumbersandletters", "displayName" =>  "John Doe"),
  );
$data_set = json_encode($data_set_pre);
```

Unfortunately, this produces:

```
{"id":"","startTime":"2017-04-14T07:47:59.028Z","endTime":"2017-04-15T07:47:59.028Z","contacts":{"id":"ahashofsomenumbersandletters","displayName":"John Doe"}}
```

I've been researching, and I'm getting the impression that json_encode will encode everything BUT an unbroken sequential array starting from 0 as an object, and I don't now how to work around this.
(No, I can't change what the API requires, it's provided by a 3rd-party).

Comment: `[]` mans multi dimensional array so put `"contacts" => array(array("id" => "ahashofsomenumbersandletters", "displayName" =>  "John Doe"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$data_set_pre = array(
    "id" => "12",
    "startTime" => "2017-04-14T07:47:59.028Z",
    "endTime" => "2017-04-15T07:47:59.028Z",
    "contacts" => array(
                    array(
                        "id" => "ahashofsomenumbersandletters", "displayName" =>  "John Doe"
                        )
                )
    );
$data_set = json_encode($data_set_pre);
```

Comment: Looks like that should work as well, haven't tried (it's the same as Mayank's answer, essentially). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change the following line:

```
"contacts" => array("id" => "ahashofsomenumbersandletters", "displayName" =>  "John Doe"),
```

to

```
"contacts" => array(array("id" => "ahashofsomenumbersandletters", "displayName" =>  "John Doe")),
```

It will give:

```
{"id":"","startTime":"2017-04-14T07:47:59.028Z","endTime":"2017-04-15T07:47:59.028Z","contacts":[{"id":"ahashofsomenumbersandletters","displayName":"John Doe"}]}
```

here `[{"id":"ahashofsomenumbersandletters","displayName":"John Doe"}]` is a multi-dimension array

Comment: But the accepted answer is not this one :D 
Enjoy dude :P